# Ionic link data to user in firebase

Tags: database, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm wondering how I can log in as a user in my ionic app, and then save some data in a list for that user. And if I log in as another user I can save some data for that user.

I've got the code to save data, and to log in as different users, now I only need to figure out how to connect the data to a specific user.

My code to save data:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular/navigation/nav-params';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import {NavController, AlertController, ActionSheetController} from "ionic-angular";

@Component({
selector: 'page-benchpress',
templateUrl: 'benchpress.html',
})

export class Benchpress { 

 benchrecords: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
constructor(private navParams: NavParams,
          public alertCtrl: AlertController,
          public navCtrl: NavController, db: AngularFireDatabase,
          public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController){
this.benchrecords = db.list('/benchrecords');
} 
addRecord(){
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Record',
  message: "Enter your new record!",
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'repmax',
      placeholder: 'Your repmax'
    },
    {
      name: 'weight',
      placeholder: 'Weight lifted'
    },
    {
      name: 'date',
      placeholder: 'ex. 2017-01-04'
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Save',
      handler: data => {
        this.benchrecords.push({
          repmax: data.repmax,
          weight: data.weight,
          date: data.date

        });
      }
    }
  ]
});
prompt.present();
}
```

My code to log in:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';



@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class Login {

    user = {} as User;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams
              ) {
  }

  async login(user: User){
    try {
      const result = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      if(result) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('Home');
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  registerUser(){
    this.navCtrl.push('Register');
  }

}
```

My Home.ts (user will come to home.html after login):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class Home {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private toast: ToastController,
              public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if (data && data.email && data.uid) {
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Welcome to APP_NAME, ${data.email}`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      }
      else {
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Could not find authentication details`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      }
    });
  }

  GoToBenchpress(){
    this.navCtrl.push('Benchpress');
  }

}
```

I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Does anyone know?